# Django: How to Convert QuerySet into String

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm using Python 3 and trying to convert a QuerySet into human-readable text. I have a line like this:

```
top_post = Post.objects.filter(category='1')[:1]
```

That prints like this:

```
<QuerySet [<Post: Test Post 1>]>
```

What makes me scratch my head is a similar QuerySet successfully converts when displayed via a template:

```
latest = Post.objects.order_by('-published_date')[:5]
```

"Latest" uses a for...loop in the template:

```
{% for latest_posts in latest %}
<h1>{{ latest_posts }}</h1>
```

While "top_post" displays only a blank:

```
<h1>{{ top_post }}</h1>
```

Anyone see what's missing?

Comment: Your top_post is a queryset, you need to get a single object something like `top_post = top_post[0]`

Answer (score 6):

`{{top_post}}` is a query set (slicing a queryset also produces a queryset), so it should display that. When you loop over the queryset, as you do over `latest`, you display the objects inside.

`{{top_post.0}}` would give you the object `top_post` contains.

Alternatively you can use

```
top_post = Post.objects.filter(category='1').first()
```

to get the object directly.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. It now lets me get on with remaining development.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the `__str__` method in the  Post model where you define what to print.
Moreover you should `.get` instead of `.filter` if you expect one object to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into list

```
def 
return(Post.objects.filter(category='1').first)
```

Comment: This solution is already provided by the nearly three year old answer from NS0. When answering older questions, please make sure that you provide a new solution, or a significantly better explanation than current answers.

Answer (score 0):

to solve it you can use nested loops (A loop in other loop)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although it might be correct, please try to elaborate more your answers, and add code snippets. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using filter then I am assuming you want more than one value else use the get method.
You can convert the queryset into a list and then play around the list.

```
top_post = list(Post.objects.filter(category='1')[:1])[0]
```

Now `top_post` will give the first object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just to pile on to last bit about getting the actual value out of the QuerySet objects.  This is what I do.

```
list_of_things = TableName.objects.all().values_list('thing', flat=True)
```

`values_list` lets me select what column(s) to return and `flat=True` extracts (for lack of a better term) each column as an object, thus loading up the list.